# Upgrading existing application with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I've created a setup file for my application, which works fine for new installations, but I now need to adapt it to handle upgrades.

I understand I should add `DisableDirPage=auto` under [Setup], so the user won't be prompted for an installation folder during upgrades?

I also do a few things in [Run]. How do I skip these actions when it's an upgrade?

Under [Files] I currently use a single line to install everything to the application folder:-

```
Source: "{#BuildOutputFolder}\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

Firstly, I'm guessing this won't work during an upgrade as "onlyifdoesntexist" would prevent the EXE and DLLs from ever being overwritten, even with newer versions?

Secondly, there are certain files (e.g. configs) that get installed, but should *never* be overwritten during an upgrade. I'm guessing the current line isn't sufficient and I would need to replace it with a number of separate lines to achieve this functionality, e.g. one to install the EXE, one for the DLLs, and one for the configs (with "onlyifdoesntexist")?

Comment: You can move the `[Run]` section into a function and put it in `[Code]` section. Then you can set a variable to identify if it's an upgrade, say `isUpgrade: boolean`. And check this variable in the function.

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly you want to do with the `[Files]` section. If you remove `onlyifdoesntexist` flag, the files with newer versions only get copied. The setup will ignore files that have same versions. Hope this help.